# PHP, listing things twice

Tags: php, foreach, arguments

I'm using this script to list a few Twitch.tv streams and their status (offline or online).

If there are no online streams found, I want it to display a text saying that all are offline.

Code that checks if the added streams are online:

```
//get's member names from stream url's and checks for online members
$channels = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($members); $i++) {
if (isset($json_array[$i])){
$title = $json_array[$i]['channel']['channel_url'];
$array = explode('/', $title);
$member = end($array);
$viewer = $json_array[$i] ['stream_count'];
onlinecheck($member, $viewer);
$checkedOnline[] = signin($member);
}
}

unset($value);
unset($i);

//checks if player streams are online
function onlinecheck($online, $viewers)
{  
//If the variable online is not equal to null, there is a good change this person is currently streaming
if ($online != null)
{
echo '<a href="http://www.twitch.tv/'.$online.'"> <strong>'.$online.'</strong></a>';
echo '&nbsp <img src="/images/online.png"><strong> Status:</strong> Online! </br>'; 
echo '<img src="/images/viewers.png"><strong>Viewers:</strong> &nbsp' .$viewers.'</br>';

}
}
```

Full code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Streamlist</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

$members = array("ncl_tv");

$userGrab = "http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=";

$checkedOnline = array (); 

foreach($members as $i =>$value){
$userGrab .= ",";
$userGrab .= $value;
}

unset($value);

$json_file = file_get_contents($userGrab, 0, null, null);
$json_array = json_decode($json_file, true);

$channels = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($members); $i++) {
if (isset($json_array[$i])){
$title = $json_array[$i]['channel']['channel_url'];
$array = explode('/', $title);
$member = end($array);
$viewer = $json_array[$i] ['stream_count'];
onlinecheck($member, $viewer);
$checkedOnline[] = signin($member);
}
}

unset($value);
unset($i);

function onlinecheck($online, $viewers) {  
if ($online != null) {
echo '<a href="http://www.twitch.tv/'.$online.'"> <strong>'.$online.'</strong></a>';
echo '&nbsp <img src="/images/online.png"><strong> Status:</strong> Online! </br>'; 
echo '<img src="/images/viewers.png"><strong>Viewers:</strong> &nbsp' .$viewers.'</br>';        
}
}

$alloffline = "All female user streams are currently offline.";

function signin($person){
if($person != null){
return $person;
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

............................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP error, Undefined offset & Undefined variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18803713/php-error-undefined-offset-undefined-variable)

Comment: I think the problem is in `$member = end($array);`, there you are getting an element of the array, and `foreach` need an array for argument. [read end()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php)

Comment: Check my post again, edited it now. I fixed the foreach error, however it's still displaying things twice.

Comment: how do you know when a member is online?

Comment: Check the post again, edited. That's the code that checks if the added streams are online, after that it's the part that displays the online streams.

Comment: If it finds no online streams, I just want it to display a text that all are offline.

Comment: There is no question in your question.

Comment: @MarinaTodorova it's a good idea to non-destructively edit - your question doesn't make much sense anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it because your `$userGrab` URL contains usernames twice? This is the URL whose contents you're retrieving:

`http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=painuser,ZombieGrub,Nathanias,Youbetterknowme,ncl_tv,painuser,ZombieGrub,Nathanias,Youbetterknowme,ncl_tv`

Having looked at the response, it doesn't look like it's causing the problem. The strange URL is a result of you appending to the `$userGrab` string in the first `foreach` loop, after you've already added them with the `implode()` function call before. I think twitch.tv is rightly ignoring duplicate channels.

If all the values in `$checkedOnline` are null, everyone is offline. Put this at the end of your first code sample:

```
$personOnline = false;

foreach($checkedOnline as $person) {
    if($person !== null) {
        $personOnline = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(!$personOnline) {
    echo 'No one is online';
}
else {
    //there is at least someone online
}
```

Comment: Hm, didn't notice that. It should be that, but how can I fix this? Like I said at the end of my post, I'm really bad at this. :(

Comment: Well, after removing the implode() call, it's still the same. Still listing the things twice.

Comment: What's the desired output? In your final `foreach`, you're outputting both `Online` and `Offline` - are you missing an `if` statement?

Comment: You also need to look at case-sensitivity - in your `$members` array, usernames are mixed case, whereas in URL responses, they're all lowercase. Try changing everything in `$members` to lowercase.

Comment: It was actually displaying them twice because of the code after <hr>, fixed that.

Comment: The last thing I want to add is, if all the streams are offline, it displays a text.. I tried adding after the IF in function onlinecheck($online, $viewers) an ELSE with echo, but it didn't work..

Comment: Can you help me with this last thing?

Comment: @MarinaTodorova I can help you, you can show a part of your array, to see how to get the offline part